# Why doesn't CGPathIsRect work?  Why doesn't CGPathContainsPoint work?

Tags: ios, vector-graphics, cgpath

I am making a CGPoint and a CGPathRef then trying to find if the CGPoint is inside the CGPathRef. Here is the code:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 0);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 200);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 200);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

CGPoint hitPoint = CGPointMake(77, 77);

if ( CGPathIsEmpty(path) )
    NSLog(@"Path Is Empty!");
else
{
    if ( CGPathIsRect(path, NULL) ) 
        NSLog(@"Path is a Rectangle!");
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Path is NOT a Rectangle!");
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, hitPoint, FALSE)) // FALSE or TRUE - same result
            NSLog(@"Hit Point Inside: x=%f, y=%f", hitPoint.x, hitPoint.y);
        else
            NSLog(@"Hit Point Outside: x=%f, y=%f", hitPoint.x, hitPoint.y);
    }
}
```

The output reads:

```
Path is NOT a Rectangle!
Hit Point Outside: x=77.000000, y=77.000000
```

The path obviously is a rectangle and the point is inside the closed path.  Please clue me in on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRectIsPath` only returns true if the path was created by `CGPathCreateWithRect` (with a `transform` parameter that doesn't rotate or skew the rectangle), or if the path was created by `CGPathCreateMutable` and had a single rectangle added to it with `CGPathAddRect`.

It would be much more work for it to figure out whether any arbitrary path is exactly a rectangle.  The path might contain bezier curve segments that are actually straight lines, or sides that are built from consecutive straight line segments.

If you need to detect whether any arbitrary path is actually just a rectangle, you will have to do it yourself using `CGPathApply`.  It will be complicated.

As for why your point-inside test isn't working: you need to use `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to create the sides of your rectangle:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 200);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 200);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```